# C++ compile time check if type has mutable fields

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, immutability

All

is it possible to get true/false flag for class having mutable field?

Could I distinguish during compilation between

```
struct A {
    private: mutable int _x;
};
```

and

```
struct B {
    private: int _x;
};
```

More complex question, is it possible to do so NOT knowing name of the field?

Comment: Since `mutable` doesn't seem to be part of the type (`mutable int* p = &_x;` is an error), I don't think this can be done.

Comment: Indeed, mutable just excludes the according element from the constification in `const` memberfunctions. (While I write this I'm wondering whether it also influences direct member accesses via a pointer to const?) Question remains is what conclusions you want to draw from this info? Maybe there are other ways to achieve this?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I would like to have "true" immutable type in my system. Having "const T..." is not enough, apparently. This is why `immutability` tag is here